# ServerSocket accept throws nullpointerexception

Tags: android, serversocket

I am having a problem with a client server app I am working on, for some reason the ServerSocket class accept message is throwing a NullPointerException when a client attempts to connect to it.

Here is the class responsible for the server:

```
public class DeviceNameServer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Utils.SERVERPORTDEVICENAME);
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(new DeviceNameRunner(clientSocket, new DefaultDeviceIdentifier()));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("CalpolException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is called by an Activity

```
nameServerThread = new Thread(new DeviceNameServer());
nameServerThread.start();
```

`nameServerThread` is a member of the Activity

This is the code responsible for connecting to the server:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();

            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIp, Utils.SERVERPORTDEVICENAME), 500);

                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                while (socket.isConnected()) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

As soon as this executes the `serverSocket.accept()` message throws a NullPointerException

Has anyone seen this before?

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:102)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:203)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:128)
            at za.co.strikemedia.calpol.babymonitor.DeviceNameServer.run(DeviceNameServer.java:17)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: why are you closing the socket in the while loop?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi Because I only read a line of text to the socket then I am done with it, I just removed that part of the code

Comment: If at the server's while loop, you dont call the thread, just accept the connection, will the error remain?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi It never gets past the `serverSocket.accept()`

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831052/socket-accept-throws-null-pointer-exception

Comment: @ZiadHalabi Nope had a look at that, the problem that guys was experiencing was that his serverSocket variable was null, but that is not the case for me

Comment: Look in and post the stacktrace/logcat. It will tll you whats happening.

Comment: @greenapps I have added the stack trace. I can confirm that `serverSocket` variable is not null

Comment: What is on DeviceNameServer line 17?

Comment: @greenapps `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`

Comment: did you find the solution? @Armand